# New to C#, can anyone explain to me how enums and setting variables for enums works?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, enums, monodevelop, unityscript

I'm sure this is a very simple question, but I'm learning how to program in C# and the "flow" of this text adventure program makes perfect sense to me, but I'm confused how  the third line "private States myState;" works.

As you can see, the program starts by setting the variable myState to States.cell, which calls a void method (not shown below) that waits for a key that changes the variable "myState" thus updating the update function.

My question is, how does the "enum" class work? It seems as though it's possible to make a variable from the "enum States" line, but I don't understand why that is. Sorry if this is a really stupid question.

Here's the code:

```
        public Text text;
private enum States {cell, sheets_0, mirror, lock_0, sheets_1, cell_mirror, lock_1, freedom};
private States myState;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    myState = States.cell;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    print (myState);
        if      (myState == States.cell){           state_cell();} 
        else if (myState == States.sheets_0){       state_sheets_0();} 
        else if (myState == States.mirror){         state_mirror();} 
        else if (myState == States.lock_0){         state_lock_0();} 
        else if (myState == States.sheets_1){       state_sheets_1();}
        else if (myState == States.cell_mirror){    state_cell_mirror();}
        else if (myState == States.lock_1){         state_lock_1();}
        else if (myState == States.freedom){        state_freedom();}
}
```

Comment: Enums just hold a series of constant values, starting from 0, unless you define the number you want to use for each of them. Also I can tell you're taking that Unity course from Udemy.

Comment: Have you considered reviewing the [relevant documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) on this C# feature?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify. I understand what enums are and their purpose, I just don't understand how you can take an enum list and apparently make a variable out of it (going from "private enum States" to "private states myState").

Comment: And yes I am taking the unity course on udemy it's really quite fun!

Comment: What `private States myState` does is declare a variable of type `States` (the enum you defined is basically a type) named "myState". As a result, you can store any of the possible values of `States` in your `myState` variable.

Comment: Thank you @Serlite, this helps a bunch. Sorry, I just don't understand the mechanics behind C# that well yet. And you can ONLY store the possible values of "States" in "myState," correct? I think that's the whole idea behind it. Thanks again, I really have no idea what I'm doing yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An enum is basically a special type that lets you define named values. You're creating a named type just as you would if you were defining a class. What your code is actually doing is first defining your enumerated type called States with all the possible named values, then declaring a variable "myState" using the enum type "States" that you defined in the line before. What you can't see in your code is that by default in c# the underlying type for your enum is an integer, and each of your possible values also has an integer value assigned to it which could be overridden if needed, so all you're really doing in your update code is an integer comparison. Is there any reason you're not using a switch instead of that big if/else block? Also you could eliminate the start function and just instantiate your myState variable like this:

```
private States myState = States.cell;
```

MSDN has pretty good documentation for it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the perfect explanation, now this makes sense. I just didn't understand the underlying function behind this.

Are most types special in this way that they can be used as both a class and as something you can set in variable formatting? 

The only reason I'm using the big if/else block is I'm an idiot and trying to learn how to program and that's all I know so far!

Comment: I'm probably going to miss one, but there are a few types that work like this: Class (obviously), Enum, Interface, delegate, and event are the ones I can think of off the top of my head that work this way.

Comment: STRUCT! struct is the one that I missed.

Answer (score 0):

by default enum are int value but can also be casted as other type

```
public enum MyEnum : byte
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2
}
```

If you intend to use the associated value as it's underlying type you'll need to cast it

```
var myByte = (byte)MyEnum.Two;
```

As per you example you should use a switch statement instead of multiple if statement it's more readeable:

```
var enumValue = MyEnum.One;
switch (enumValue)
{
    case MyEnum.One:
        //Do Something here.
        break;
    case MyEnum.Two:
        //Do something else here.
        break;
    default:
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you so much. But, let clarify, I do understand the purpose and use of enums and how they function, what I don't understand is how you can apparently make a variable out of an enum list (going from "private enum States" to "private states myState").

Is this possible with any class? In the C# documentation they mention you can make variables out of enums, but don't expand on that.

Comment: You might want to look at enum as a collection of constants. and yes you can declare a class property as a enum, I actually do it all the time with my MVC Model classes. The value of using enum is to make your code easier to read mostly instead of remembering that a class property ex: user.country = 1 means USA user.country = Country.Usa is self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple:
the porpose of this line:

```
private enum States {cell, sheets_0, mirror, lock_0, sheets_1, cell_mirror, lock_1, freedom};
```

Is to define an enum named "States"

The porpose of the line after it:

```
private States myState;
```

Is to create an instance of the type "State" named "my state"